# sail file does not run -syntax error near unexpected token?

Tags: php, wsl-2, laravel-sail

[image]

when I put the sail command, it shows this error.

Can someone help me?

```
docker/sail: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `$'$file2\r''
'ocker/sail: line 4: `case "${UNAMEOUT}" in  $file1 $file2
```

Comment: How you run docker with sail ?

Comment: actually I'm trying to start the project with the command sail in the terminal.
Then when I give this command, this error appears.

Comment: Do you want me to send some prints and explain better visually?

Comment: Tural, I left an answer below with the prints and my doubt more explained.

Comment: Maybe revert the file back to original as the \r seems like it doesn't belong there.